# How do i add a summation column to my table on Rails 4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have an already existing table "registers" with columns; `:full_name, :amount_paid, :user_id, :course_id`.
I also have the course table with columns: `:title, :price`.

I want to add a column to my registers table that calculate the balance from the `register.course.price` and the register.

so I tried

`rails g migration add_balance_to_registers balance:"register.course.price - register.amount_paid"`

but when I try

```
rake db:migrate
```

I get an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the field to `registers` table, then populate it with appropriate values.

First you add field with new `migration`

`rails g migration addBalanceToRegisters balance:float`

Then start migraation to add the field to `registers` table
`rake db:migrate`

But field `balance` will be empty, now you have to populate it.

You could create `rake` task for this.

Inside `lib/tasks/` folder add new file `registers.rake`.

Inside `registers.rake` add folowing code:

```
namespace :registers do
  desc "populate registers balance with appropriate balance amount"
  task :sync_balance => :environment do
    Register.all.each do |r|
      b = r.course.price - r.amount_paid
      r.update balance: b
    end
  end
end
```

Then run this `rake` task, like

`rake registers:sync_balance`